# What is best practice for creating a constructor? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python and I studied constructors but while doing some trainings, a question came to my mind about what would be the best practice while creating the constructor.

I'm creating a snake module that helps me in creating a snake instance (snake that has 3 segments) and I created it within the constructor itself this way:

```
from turtle import Turtle
STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            self.snake_segment = Turtle("square")
            self.snake_segment.color("white")
            self.snake_segment.penup()
            self.snake_segment.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(self.snake_segment)
```

But I saw another way of creating it by using a function outside the constructor and calling it within the constructor:

```
from turtle import Turtle
STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            new_snake_segment = Turtle("square")
            new_snake_segment.color("white")
            new_snake_segment.penup()
            new_snake_segment.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(new_snake_segment)
```

I'm wondering which way is better and why?
Is how I created it wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's no point in using `self.snake_segment`, since you're not going to re-use that attribute later. Also, as it is currently written, the `create_snake` method is only useful if you intend to call it more than once - but that would duplicate all the segments, which looks like a bug. Rather than worrying about "best practice" (which often has no useful definition, or is merely a matter of opinion), you should instead think more clearly about *what you want the code to do*, and test it thoroughly (i.e. try to imagine all the ways in which it could go wrong).

Comment: "best practice" can be defined as the design patterns for a particular problem that have been found to avoid most unnecessary problems while implementing most common requirements. "Best practice" is rarely opinion. It's usually about practical, evidence based lessons with genuine improvements that have been learned by competent practiconers working in the problem space. "Best practice" is not an opinion, though it may be conditional on particular requirements. It's certainly a fair question to seek what best practice may be for any problem. And, no, it's not off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several interacting considerations here:

1. failure inside `__init__` fails to construct the object
2. re-use of code
3. clear organisation and documentation of code
4. minor code differences such as using an attribute instead of a local

Separation of `create_snake` into it's own method **(#3)**, with a name that documents it's purpose, clarifies and organises the code to make it quicker to understand and modify and potentially more robust (in principle, possibly of negligible difference in this case). Identifier names are arguably the single most important element of code documentation, in this case "create snake". I think this is a good argument for using snake case identifiers.

At this point in the development there's no indication whether `create_snake` will be called at any other time for this object, but if later you do need to `create_snake` again, for the same object, this separation of the `create_snake` code keeps it [DRY](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/429660/the-dont-repeat-yourself-dry-principle-in-documentation) **(#2)**.

In Python, `__init__` always returns `None`. It's not a "proper" method from that point of view. Any failures inside the `__init__` method will mean the object is not created, potentially requiring a `try...except` wrapper **(#1)**. Work should be minimised within `__init__` **(#1)** for this reason.

In your implementation here, moving the code out into `create_snake` doesn't actually fix that, because it's still *called* from `__init__`. This can be improved by calling `create_snake` *after* the object is created, but that slightly complicates the usage pattern, and may not be justified in this instance (depends on your planning).

(The reason I found this question in the first place was because I was seeking clarification of a vague memory I have of some article arguing that doing work inside `__init__` is an anti-pattern.)

To take this concept even further, you can create a practically empty object, and leave snake creation, and any other work, to lazy methods that are only called when needed. You can find further [discussion on approaches](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357937/is-it-really-correct-to-declare-all-instance-attributes-in-init/).

There are other code considerations that may possibly be incidental to your core question **(#4)**. For instance, there's no point in using an instance attribute (`self.snake_segment`) when you never use that value after the method completes, because it just makes the object heavier and requires more variable look-ups. Depending on your wider code organisation, it may also be better to keep class related constants (`STARTING_POSITIONS`) inside the class, rather than at the module level. I'm not stating that is the case for you; it depends very much on what your wider code is doing.

As an overall answer I'd say that your second approach is definitely better, and most probably good enough as well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I just noticed now there was a response to my question. Thank you again.

Comment: No worries, @Bumblebee, it's not too late to mark it as the accepted answer.